# how to search BLE device after logout in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

In my case search view is one controller and logout is in another viewcontroller ,how can i disconnect bluetooth and logout.Once i logout device is not forget and it is keeping connected to my device.How can i search for blue devices in my app afterlogout?please help me .Thanks in advance

```
    - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{

    NSLog(@"%s \n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");


    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        [mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES }];

        return;
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");

    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");


    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }

}

    - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
    {

        NSLog(@"I see an advertisement with identifer: %@, state: %ld name: %@, services: %@, description: %@",[peripheral identifier],(long)[peripheral state],[peripheral name],[peripheral services],[advertisementData description]);
        // Name of the device
        NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];

        NSLog(@"The name get from direct periperal --> %@",localName);

        if (![localName length] > 0) {
            NSLog(@"localName is null ");

        }
        else
        {
        if (peripheral != (id)[NSNull null] && peripheral.name != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            NSLog(@"-----> Clear Check Point 1 <------");
            if (localName==nil )
            {
                NSLog(@"-----> Clear Check Point 2 <------");
                localName=peripheral.name;
                NSLog(@"The name get if we get nil from periperal name --> %@",localName);
            }


            if (peripheral == nil || peripheral.name == (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                NSLog(@"-----> Clear Check Point 3 <------");
            }


                [peripheralsarray addObject:peripheral];
                [peripheralnamesarray addObject:localName];


                NSOrderedSet *mySet = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:peripheralnamesarray];
                peripheralnamesarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[mySet array]];

                NSOrderedSet *mySet2 = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:peripheralsarray];
                peripheralsarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[mySet2 array]];
                [mgr stopScan];


            }
        }
    }
}



- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error { 
    NSLog(@"%s \n",PRETTY_FUNCTION); 
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
    appDelegate.isBLE_Connected = FALSE; 
    [mgr cancelPeripheralConnection:activeperipheral]; 
    UIAlertView *disconnALert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No device is paired" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
    [disconnALert show];
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply disconnect your peripheral when required?

Comment: i don't know how to disconnect peripheral but i use did disconnect peripheral method but it didn't.can u help me?

Comment: - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s \n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.isBLE_Connected = FALSE;
     [mgr cancelPeripheralConnection:activeperipheral];
    UIAlertView *disconnALert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No device is paired" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [disconnALert show];
    
    
    
}this is code i had using

Comment: `cancelPeripheralConnection` cancels a pending connect.  To disconnect from a peripheral that you have an active connection to  you need to call `[peripheral disconnect]`

Comment: ok thanks and i have small doubt can u clarify me central manager delegate methods are in one view controller and logout is another view control if i want to disconnect peripheral i can write only disconnect peripheral method  or all the delegate methods?

Comment: [peripheral disconnect] i am trying you answer but cbperipheral not declares disconnect method ,i am using iOS 8.3

Comment: Apologies, `cancelPeripheralConnection` is the correct method - can you check that `mgr` is not null.  I would suggest that you use a single class to manage your bluetooth operations - perhaps with a delegate to view controllers where required

Comment: ok i will check and  come again